# Solve the Polynomial Equation.

Tags: polynomials

How would I go about solving this problem?

$$3x^3 + 6x^2 = 9x + 18$$

I know to move the variables to other side of course, but what's the next move?

Comment: $3x^2(x+2)=9(x+2)$.  So either $3x^2=9$ or $x=-2$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: thank you. I understand now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could collect all terms on the same side and proceed. Here is another slightly different way. Note that $3x^3+6x^2 = 3x^2(x+2)$ and $9x+18 = 9(x+2)$. We hence get
$$3x^2(x+2) = 9(x+2)$$
Hence, either $x+2$ or $0$ or $3x^2 = 9$. I trust you can finish it off from here.

Comment: Enlightening! thanks so much.